# how to implement browser back and forward button using python.. i am making my own browser using pyqt5 and want to implement back & forward btn

Tags: python, browser, pyqt5

I am creating a web browser using python and pyqt5.. i have done all gui and backend also but i also want to implement back and forward feature in my browser.. Can i store visited urls in  one list and then manipulate that list so that i can go back and forward to specific link whenever the user click back or forward btn? If it is possible how to do it? I want to go to previous visited url when user clicks back btn and same for forward also.. like chrome does when we click back and forward btn..

**Here's the browser i made**[image: Browser made with pyqt5]

> So when i visit some urls in the same tab and then when i click back btn .. it should go to previous page and so for forward btn when i click forward. how to implement it? Does storing visited url in list and then manipulating that list when user clicks the btn helps? whats the process to achieve this functionality?

Comment: See [`QWebEngineView.history()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#history).

Comment: [QWebEngineView.back()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#back), [QWebEngineView.forward()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#forward).